# Trying to use midasr in R but getting some error

Tags: r, regression, midasr

I am trying to do a simple regression using high frequency data to estimate low frequency data. In my case I am using cpi monthly data to estimate gdp quarterly data.

I am using the following code:

```
library(fredr)
fredr_set_key("mykey"
library(midasr)
library(quantmod)
library(fredr)
library(tidyverse)

 gdp <- fredr(
   series_id = "GDP",
   observation_start = as.Date("2021-01-01"),
   observation_end = as.Date("2022-12-31")
 )
 gdp=subset(gdp, select=value)

cpi <- fredr(
series_id = "CORESTICKM159SFRBATL",
observation_start = as.Date("2021-01-01"),
observation_end = as.Date("2022-12-31")
)
cpi=subset(cpi, select=value)



t <- 1:length(gdp)
gdp %>% mutate(value = as.numeric(value))
is.numeric(gdp$value)
cpi %>% mutate(value = as.numeric(value))
is.numeric(cpi$value)


mr <- midas_r(gdp$value~t+fmls(cpi$value,2,3, nealmon), data=list(gdp=gdp, cpi=cpi),        start=list(x=c(0,0,0)))
```

The example I am following is this:

```
data("USunempr")
data("USrealgdp")
y <- diff(log(USrealgdp))
x <- window(diff(USunempr),start=1949)
t <- 1:length(y)
mr <- midas_r(y~t+fmls(x,11,12,nealmon),start=list(x=c(0,0,0)))
```

The error I am getting now is Error in mls(x, 0:k, m, ...) : Incomplete high frequency data